# How to get distinct string values based on search filter

Tags: c#, list, loops, for-loop

I have list of string values and string filter (which may contain 1 or 2 words). I want to retrieve all distinct values from that list of strings till only words present in filter.

I have below list:

```
DEPRI-LOOP 15502 Bulk
DELETE-LOOP 15500 PAIL
DELETE-LOOP 15667 PAIL
OBSOLATE-LOOP 15834 PAIL
DO NOT USE - LOOP 15835 Conc Bulk
LOOP 15000 Bulk
LOOP 15000 Drum, Stg
LOOP 15002 Bulk
LOOP 15002 Drum, Stg
LOOP 15002 LA
LOOP 15250B Bulk
LOOP 15250C Conc Mat
LOOP 15250D Bulk
LOOP 15250D Drum, Stg
LOOP 15400 Bulk
LOOP 15400 Bulk Mat
LOOP 15400 Drum, Stg
LOOP 15500 Bulk
LOOP 15500 Conc Mat
LOOP 15500 Conc Filt Bulk
LOOP 15500 Bulk Mat
LOOP 15500 Drum, Stg
LOOP 15500 IBC BR
LOOP 15500 LA
LOOP 15667 Bulk
LOOP 15667 Conc Mat
LOOP 15667 Conc Filt Bulk
LOOP 15667 Drum, Stg
LOOP 15668 Bulk
LOOP 15668 Conc Bulk
LOOP 15668 Drum, Stg
LOOP 15668D Bulk
LOOP 15668D Drum, Stg
LOOP 15833 Bulk
LOOP 15833 Drum, Stg
LOOP 15834 Bulk
LOOP 15835 Bulk
```

String filter value is "LOOP 15", then my resultset will contain below list:

```
LOOP 15502
LOOP 15500
LOOP 15667
LOOP 15834
LOOP 15835
LOOP 15000
LOOP 15002
LOOP 15250B
LOOP 15250C
LOOP 15250D
etc.
```

Since, filter string contains 2 words, I need to take distinct of 2 words only.
I am struggling lot with this issue and couldn't find proper resolution.

Comment: Store the list of strings in a tree where each distinct word is a node - match the search terms against the next level of nodes in the tree one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions to match your filter and return the words based on word boundaries. A little bit of LINQ will get you the Distinct values only:

```
class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<String> data = BuildList();
        String filter = "LOOP 15";
        String regexPattern = @"\b\w*" + filter + @"\w*\b";
        var results = data.Where(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, regexPattern)).Select(line => Regex.Match(line, regexPattern).Value).Distinct();
        foreach (String match in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Quit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<String> BuildList()
    {
        List<String> values = new List<String>();
        values.Add("DEPRI-LOOP 15502 Bulk");
        values.Add("DELETE-LOOP 15500 PAIL");
        values.Add("DELETE-LOOP 15667 PAIL");
        values.Add("OBSOLATE-LOOP 15834 PAIL");
        values.Add("DO NOT USE - LOOP 15835 Conc Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15000 Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15000 Drum, Stg");
        values.Add("LOOP 15002 Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15002 Drum, Stg");
        values.Add("LOOP 15002 LA");
        values.Add("LOOP 15250B Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15250C Conc Mat");
        values.Add("LOOP 15250D Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15250D Drum, Stg");
        values.Add("LOOP 15400 Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15400 Bulk Mat");
        values.Add("LOOP 15400 Drum, Stg");
        values.Add("LOOP 15500 Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15500 Conc Mat");
        values.Add("LOOP 15500 Conc Filt Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15500 Bulk Mat");
        values.Add("LOOP 15500 Drum, Stg");
        values.Add("LOOP 15500 IBC BR");
        values.Add("LOOP 15500 LA");
        values.Add("LOOP 15667 Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15667 Conc Mat");
        values.Add("LOOP 15667 Conc Filt Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15667 Drum, Stg");
        values.Add("LOOP 15668 Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15668 Conc Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15668 Drum, Stg");
        values.Add("LOOP 15668D Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15668D Drum, Stg");
        values.Add("LOOP 15833 Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15833 Drum, Stg");
        values.Add("LOOP 15834 Bulk");
        values.Add("LOOP 15835 Bulk");
        return values;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
LOOP 15502
LOOP 15500
LOOP 15667
LOOP 15834
LOOP 15835
LOOP 15000
LOOP 15002
LOOP 15250B
LOOP 15250C
LOOP 15250D
LOOP 15400
LOOP 15668
LOOP 15668D
LOOP 15833
Press Enter to Quit.
```